# Use the Same LINQ Expression for Similar Classes

Tags: c#, linq

Some of my classes have properties with the same name. I'd like to use a generic function to return a list of these objects' property values with something like this:

```
public void List<string> GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> expression) where T : class
{
    var all = new MyEntities<T>().GetAll();
    return all.Select(expression).ToList();
}
```

then I could call the function like:

```
var allBookNames = GetValue<Book>(x => x.Name)
var allCustomerNames = GetValue<Customer>(x => x.Name)
```

The line `all.Select(express).ToList()` obviously doesn't work. How should I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry. I'm an idiot. The problem is the GetAll() method was returning an ICollection, which doesn't have the Select method. I just need to call As Queryable(). Sorry to waste your time.

I'll close this post.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Do you get error? Compile time or run time? Its giving empty result?

Comment: It doesn't work because EF doesn't like passed expression values

Comment: `public void List <string>` . That's wrong. It should be `public List<string>` only.

Comment: @Cheta, good eye. That was actually a typo. I typed the code in instead of copying and pasting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understood properly!

I am guessing you are using Entity Framework and you can achieve this with repository pattern. All you need to implement a method which will return DbSet for provided entity:

```
public DbSet<T> GetValue<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return context.Set<T>();
}
```

Then you can call:

```
repository.GetValue<Book>().Select(p => p.Name == "John");
```

It will returns Books with name John.

Please read about `Set<T>()` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx).